# Second Order Cauchy-Euler Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the problem:
$(x^2-x+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(x^2+x)\frac{dy}{dx}+(x+1)y=0$.

I've tried using the substitution $y=x^r$, and that gives me a long string of r's and x's and exponents that I'm not sure what to do with: $(r-1)x^{r-2}(r(x^2-x+1)-x^2(x+1))=0$.  From what I understand of the Cauchy-Euler method, I'm supposed to find the characteristic equation, but I don't see how to from the initial result.

Comment: This is actually not a Cauchy-Euler Equation

Comment: Oh, why is that?

Comment: Check the definition. A Cauchy-Euler equation has the form $$ax^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + bx\frac{dy}{dx} + cy = 0$$

Comment: All right, that makes sense.  Is there another term for this type of equation?

Comment: What do you mean by "another term"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious solution is $y=x$

We use the classical method to reduce the degree of the ODE which consists in the change of function $y(x)=xf(x)$

$y'=xf'+f$ and $y''=xf''+2f'$

$$(x^2-x+1)(xf''+2f')-(x^2+x)(xf'+f)+(x+1)xf=0$$
$$(x^2-x+1)xf''+(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)f'=0$$
Let $g(x)=f'$
$$(x^2-x+1)xg'+(-x^3+x^2-2x+2)g=0$$
This method reduces the ODE to a separable first order one.
$$\frac{g'}{g}=\frac{x^3-x^2+2x-2}{(x^2-x+1)x}$$
$$\ln(g)=x-2\ln(x)+\ln(x^2-x+1)+constant$$
$$g=c_1e^x\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2}$$
$$f=c_1e^x\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+c_2$$
$$y=c_1e^x(x-1)+c_2x$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, it was very helpful!

Comment: How is $y = x$ an "obvious" solution? What's the basis for guessing it?

Comment: It takes only a few minutes to check the most simple usual functions and see if, by chance, one of them is a solution. Of course, if not, we have to try more complicated methods.